# 404 Error On HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to check if an username is available on a specific webiste but it comes up with an 404 error.

```
Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/" + userToCheck & "/")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

        Dim sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim steamResult As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()

        If steamResult.Contains("Sorry") Then
            addAvailable()
```

Althought this works:

```
 Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" + userToCheck)
            Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

            Dim sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
            Dim steamResult As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()

            If steamResult.Contains("The specified profile could not be found.") Then
                addAvailable()
            End If
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: If the user doesn't exist, wouldn't you *expect* a 404?

Comment: Yup, but the program stops when it gives an 404. I want it to keep running even if it gives the 404.

Comment: Define "stops", is it throwing an exception? If so add a `Try/Catch` block.

Comment: I added another function that works, idk what's wrong witth the first one...

Answer (score 0):

If by "stops" you mean that it's throwing a exception, you'll have to wrap your code in a try catch in order to continue execution.

```
Try
        Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/" + userToCheck & "/")
        Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

        Dim sReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim steamResult As String = sReader.ReadToEnd()

        If steamResult.Contains("Sorry") Then
            addAvailable()
    Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

EDIT: Do whatever you would want to do in the case of a 404 in the catch block :)

Comment: The thing is that it is saying that the username is available when it isn't :/ And if I put "404" instead of "Sorry" it seems to work but not properly, but If I put "Sorry" instead of "404" it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielAndré Your stream reader is not loading the actual page, but rather a 404 resource, hence why you're trying to read 404 and it works. If you want to use "sorry" for whatever reason, look into WebClients.

Comment: Pressed enter to add a new line and it made a comment, accidental. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx check this and look at WebClient.DownloadString()

Comment: What's the difference between HttpWebRequest.Contains and WebClient.DownloadString.Contains?